# How to remove the same name occurrences in mysql left join?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am using the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ph.module_head_id,
  ph.module_head, pm.module_id, 
  pm.module_name, pm.module_url
FROM pms_module_header ph
LEFT JOIN pms_module pm
ON ph.module_head_id = pm.module_head_id
```

Now i am getting the following output

```
Module_head_id  Module_head module_id module_name module_url
  1               dashboard     Null    Null        Null
  2                Employee      1      Add        test.php
  2                Employee      2      View       test1.php
  3               Report         3      Project    project.php
  3               Report         4      Client     client.php
```

How to remove the same name occurences in module_head

I Want to display the out like these in codeigniter view

```
dashboard
  Employee Add 
           View
  Report   Project
           Client
```

I am using array_unique function but its not work.Please help me

Comment: Do you want to show output like that in view ?

Comment: yes,i want display in codeigniter view.Is it available any php function.

Comment: Check my Edit part of answer

Comment: Its working perfectly,Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT ph.module_head_id,
  ph.module_head, pm.module_id, 
  pm.module_name, pm.module_url
FROM pms_module_header ph
LEFT JOIN pms_module pm
ON ph.module_head_id = pm.module_head_id
group by ph.module_head_id
```

Just apply group by on module_head_id, it will work.

**EDIT**

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Module head</th>
        <th>Module name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $module_head = '';
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        if ($v['module_head'] == '' || $v['module_head'] != $module_head) {
            $module_head = $v['module_head'];
            echo $v['module_head'] . "<br/>";
        } else {
            echo " ";
        }
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<td>" . $v['module_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<tr>";
    }
    ?>
    <table>
```

Manipulate as per your view. It will work.

Comment: User doesn't specified anything like that. But my query is working fine. Why downvote ?

Comment: It is not mandatory to use aggregate function when using group by.

Comment: what i mean is it will give the last found result based on specified column so it may not give what you need.